# How to use awk to print only lines containing 5 columns

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, gawk

I have a file which contains pipe delimited data. I want to print the lines which have only 5 columns.
I tried the below. It does not work. It simply prints all the lines. Could you please let me know how to do it correctly. Thank you!

Contents of the file:

```
10413300|Maintenance Stock Clerk A - Michelle Hanley | Michelle Hanley (1680654)|Filled||10402112
10413301|Maintenance Stock Clerk - dasda|space||10402122
MOM Parkcentrum F;Alkotás u. 53.||34535|34345|asd
Business Center Naberezhnaya Tower" Block C"|||3453|ffg|345
```

Here I'm trying to print lines which have 5 columns only.

```
$ gawk -F "|" '{ if (NF=5) print $0 }' data3
10413300 Maintenance Stock Clerk A - Michelle Hanley   Michelle Hanley (1680654) Filled
10413301 Maintenance Stock Clerk - dasda space  10402122
MOM Parkcentrum F;Alkotás u. 53.  34535 34345 asd
Business Center Naberezhnaya Tower Block C   3453 ffg
```

The output shows that 2 out 4 lines have more than 5 columns.

```
$ gawk -F "|" '{print NF}' data3
6
5
5
6
```

Answer (score 15):

`NF=5` is an assignment, testing values is done with `==`.  Like this:

```
awk -F \| 'NF==5' data3
```

Comment: Confusing assignment and comparison operators is one of the most-common problems in "programming" (in the broadest sense of the term). It's very easy, especially in a *nix command-line environment, where Bourne shell and descendants interpret `Variable=value` as assignment but `Variable = value` as comparison